# using a variable in jquery load() not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

this is ultimately frustrating, because it was working on the development site, but after moving it to the live site, it stopped working. :S

```
$('.menu_btn').click(function(e) {
//rel is used to tell me what html page to load
var url = $(this).attr('rel');
//load the new page into the div
$('#ajax_wrapper').load(url);
});
```

the even more frustrating thing is, when i hard code the value of url in:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/pages/home.html'
```

it works without problems.

adding an `alert(url)` gives me the correct rel address.

Comment: The link you click what do it look like ??

Comment: can we get more code? context of attaching the click event and the html it's affecting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the domain in the URL the same as the domain of the page? If not, the problem you're having is because

> Due to browser security restrictions,
>   most "Ajax" requests are subject to
>   [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request
>   can not successfully retrieve data
>   from a different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol.

via the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: same domain, different subdomain... would that be the issue?

Comment: again... "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, **subdomain** , or protocol."

Comment: alright, it was that... thanks for the help. feel silly that it was something so simple.

Comment: @psolms don't be. If a method call refuses to do what you tell it to, it should reasonably throw an exception telling you what the problem is. It shouldn't leave you hanging, wondering why it isn't working.